# SPO Provider hosted Client web part not storing session cookie

Tags: session-cookies, sharepoint-online, web-parts, provider-hosted

I have a provider hosted app which uses SharePoint Context filter for authenticating users. I'm storing the context token generated in the first request in a session variable and using it in subsequent calls.

When I click on the app in site contents and get redirected to the provider hosted app, everything is working fine.

But when I navigate to a page in SharePoint Online which has a Client Webpart hosted in the provider hosted app, session does not work.

On inspecting the request headers sent by the App webpart and the app when it is opened directly, I found that `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie is not getting stored in the app webpart but when the provider hosted app is navigated directly.

Also I found that `SPCacheKey` cookie is being stored in both cases only Session cookie is not getting stored when loading via app web part.

I tested this in Chrome as well as IE and both are giving same output.

I tried modifying the web.config as per this [link](https://technovert.com/how-to-solve-ie-iframe-sharepoint-context-issue-using-p3p-policy/)

```
  <system.webServer>    
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="p3p" value="CP=&quot;IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT&quot;"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

But it didnt solve the issue. Because of the session not getting stored, Every ajax call in my provider hosted app is getting redirected to appredirect.aspx which is throwing

> Access to xmlhttprequest at https://tenant.sharepoint.com from origin https://providerhosted.domain blocked by cors policy no access

Why is the ASP.NET Session Id cookie not getting stored when loading via app webpart? 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching solution for this problem using many different keywords in google, finally found a solution. It looks like this is an Iframe issue. As the app web part loads inside an iframe, the session cookies are not stored inside iframe.

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59757362/5088712)  and this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer-blog/net-update-on-azure-breaking-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app/ba-p/1132149#), adding the `cookieSameSite=None` attribute in the `sessionState` of `web.config` fixed the issue.

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None"  cookieless="false" timeout="360"> 
</sessionState>
```

As usual, this was caused by an update release by MS which changed the default value of `cookieSameSite` attribute of Session cookies from `None` to `Lax`